# Figures are missing from referenced patent

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20160304516](https://www.google.com/patents/US20160304516)

Why are figures missing and PDF unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

Some Google issue maybe.

Click on the Espacenet link (next to the USPTO). It will open you the Espacenet platform with the US patent application and its relevant patent family. Choose "original document" and then "download".

The Espacenet is supported by the EPO (European Patent Office). I am a great fan!